# How to stop matplotlib.pyplot.show() from removing all figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib

After plotting several figures with *matplotlib*, I can keep track of figures by `plt.get_fignums()`.  But if I call `plt.show()` and then `plt.get_fignums()` will return an empty list. Afterwards, when I call `plt.show()`, it is simply ignored.

Question: Is there any equivalent function to `plt.show()` to show all figures in maintained by *matplotlib* that does not affect the internal state of *matplotlib* and can be called multiple times with same results?

I know that

```
for fn in plt.get_fignums():
    plt.figure(fn).show()
```

will do the job. But is there a built-in solution?

Comment: What you are describing does not match my mental model of how `show` should work.  I suspect that you are not using this _not_ in interactive mode and are then closing your figures which (rightly!) deletes them.

Comment: What did you mean by "not using this not in interactive mode"? I am in  the state of `plt.interactive('off')`.